# rails enumでマルチチェックボックスの日本語化

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[railsのフォームでマルチチェックボックスを実現したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14891/rails%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%A7%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E7%8F%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

こちらを参考にenumのマルチチェックボックスを実装してみました。enum_helpを使って日本語化しているのですが、form画面での日本語化が出来ません。どなたかご存知の方いらっしゃいますでしょうか？

form以外での表示は日本語化出来ています。この記事ですとmaker_i18n

もしお分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

I18n.t(maker)で表示されました。ありがとうございました。